# How to concatenate offset range in countif

Tags: excel, concatenation, formula, countif

I have formula in Excel that tells me if combination of columns has already occurred in previous rows. I use it as array formula.

```
{=MATCH([@[col1]]&[@[col2]],$K$9:K11&$H$9:H11)}
```

I tried also COUNTIF but it does not work like this.

Thing is that I need to change this absolute referencing to relative.

So far the most elegant solution was to use OFFSET function (rows start in 10th line):

```
{=MATCH([@[col1]]&[@[col2]],OFFSET([@[col1]],-(ROW()-10),0,ROW()-9,1)&OFFSET([@[col2]],-(ROW()-10),0,ROW()-9,1))}
```

Unfortunately this approach does not work. Somebody workaround?

Does not matter if I get count or just true/false.

[image: Does not matter if I get count or just true/false]

Comment: Can you provide some source data?  i.e. a screenshot or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolve this by creating custom function in VBA:

```
Function FIRSTOCCURANCE(StartFromRow As Integer, _
                             val1 As Range, _
                             val2 As Range) As Boolean

Dim RangeX() As Variant, RangeY() As Variant, RangeZ() As Variant, Concat() As Variant
Dim lastRow As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer: j = 0
lastRow = val1.Row - 1

RangeX = Range(Cells(StartFromRow, val1.Column), Cells(lastRow, val1.Column)).Value
RangeY = Range(Cells(StartFromRow, val2.Column), Cells(lastRow, val2.Column)).Value
'when assigning from range always is 2-D array

For i = LBound(RangeX, 1) To UBound(RangeX, 1)
    ReDim Preserve Concat(j)
    Concat(j) = RangeY(i, 1) & RangeX(i, 1)
    j = j + 1
Next i

FIRSTOCCURANCE = IsError(Application.Match(val2.Value & val1.Value, Concat, 0))

End Function
```

Comment: If somebody knows how to improve performance or how to do this with any number of columns, please let me know.